# Send JavaScript value from UI to C++ program using Ultralight

Tags: c++

I am using Ultralight: https://github.com/ultralight-ux/Ultralight and it has been multiple years since I last worked with C++ and I am just a hobby programmer that likes to tinker with stuff.

The question I have:

I want to send a simple string from the UI of the program to the program itself, I know how to send a value from the program to the UI as it was shown in their example on their GitHub: https://github.com/ultralight-ux/Ultralight/blob/master/samples/Tutorial%204%20-%20JavaScript/main.cpp .

How can I reverse the function to send to UI instead of receving?

I have tried storing the thisObject and args in their a variable and then re-use them but it gave me the error:
`non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member`

I also looked on their API page but that did not contain anything valuable that I could really understand: https://ultralig.ht/api/1_0/classultralight_1_1_j_s_value.html

I might be doing this entirely wrong, anyhow I would be more than glad for any help!